Can MongoDB/Fireworks run on a supercomputing cluster?
I'm trying to set up MongoDB and Fireworks on a supercomputing cluster, but I've encountered several issues.
OpenSSL and Shared Libraries:
Initially, MongoDB couldn't find the required libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file.
I compiled and installed OpenSSL 1.0.2 in my home directory, but MongoDB still couldn't find the necessary libraries or complained about missing version information.
When I tried to run ./mongo, it threw errors related to GLIBC_2.18 not being found, and some libraries had "no version information available."
Attempts to Resolve:
I attempted to update OpenSSL using yum, but it requires root privileges which I do not have.
I recompiled OpenSSL with the shared and -fPIC options to ensure it generates the shared library files, but it still didn't resolve the issue.
I also checked the existing OpenSSL versions on the system using which openssl and openssl version, but the paths and versions didn't align with what MongoDB required.
Sorry for the
redundant information since i'm new to the field. By the way I'm trying to reproduce the wherewulff project so I need to use the pymongo and other packages.
TLDR:

The computing nodes have no internet connection, but the login nodes do have internet access.
I do not have sudo privileges.

Has anyone successfully installed and run MongoDB and Fireworks on such a
supercomputing cluster?

+1. Welcome to our community.

My recommendation is to ask the cluster administration how the different environments work.

Sounds like you didn't compile Mongo from scratch, since it is trying to find a library that isn't found on your system. Or you didn't set up the environment paths (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) properly.
